# Can i send an event to AWS eventbridge just using a HTTP client?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

Do i need to use an AWS sdk or another AWS service if i want to trigger an event in AWS eventbridge? I would prefer to just use an http endpoint to send an event json but i'm not sure this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to sign the HTTP requests with your AWS credentials. The algorithm for signing the request is described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/create-signed-request.html). It is certainly possible to do this in your own code, but most people find it much easier to simply include the AWS SDK, or call the AWS CLI tool, to perform this action.